# Issues with Regex Dictionary and Definitions

Tags: python, regex

Apologies for probably a dumb question, but very green at Python here.

I am trying to parse a txt file by using regex and instructions found here: https://www.vipinajayakumar.com/parsing-text-with-python/

I'm having two issues:
1) Regex dictionary only ever matches one value: all three of my definitions "match" when the ones above are commented out, but only one matches when passed the line of the file.  I also verified that different lines are being passed to the _parse_line function each time.

2) \d and \d+ don't seem to be working - the only time I get a match is if I use .* - I've read through the way regex works several times and it seems straight forward, but I simply can't get this to work.

Many thanks for any and all input.

```
rx_dict = {
    'serial': re.compile(r'SERIAL\s(?P<serial>\d+)\n'),
    'operation': re.compile(r'MODE\s(?P<operation>.*)\n'),
    'ch': re.compile(r'CHANNEL\s(?P<ch>.*)\n')
}


#line parser

def _parse_line(echo):

    for value, rx in rx_dict.items():
        match = rx.search(echo)
        print (match)
        if match:
                return value, match
        return None, None
```

Comment: Have you solved the issue? If not please share a sample line you test against and provide expected results. Note you *must* post full relevant code snippet to repro the issue, the code above is *NOT* enough to understand where what fails.

Answer (score 0):

It appears you have an indentation problem. If the first regex in the dictionary does not match, you never get to try the others. Don't you mean:

```
def _parse_line(echo):

    for value, rx in rx_dict.items():
        match = rx.search(echo)
        print (match)
        if match:
                return value, match
    return None, None # outdent
```

If `\d*` matches, but `\d+`, does not, then you do *not* have a number following `SERIAL`.

Comment: Thanks...definitely a noob mistake on the indentation.

\d* does not return either.  The match.group() outputs look like this:
                            1

I can easily shed the whitespace, but why isn't it ignoring that when I specify it's there with /s?

Comment: @RyanWogh You need to show exactly what the complete *input* is and then what you expect the output match to be, i.e a MInimal Reproducible Example. This is a basic prerequisite to getting a good answer.